# Find the values of $m$ in the 2nd degree equation $mx^2-2(m-1)x-m-1=0$ so that it has one root between $-1$ and $2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, roots, quadratics

Find the values of $m$ in the 2nd degree equation $mx^2-2(m-1)x-m-1=0$ so that it has only one root between $-1$ and $2$.

Like in this [almost identical question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14742/find-the-values-of-m-in-the-2nd-degree-equation-3m-2x22mx3m-0-so-that) there are two ways to solve this, one is acknowledging that $f(-1)f(2) \lt 0$, the other applying the theorems for the two possible scenarios $x_1 \lt -1 \lt x_2 \lt 2$ and $-1 \lt x_1 \lt 2 \lt x_2$.

Doing $f(-1)f(2)<0$, we have:
$
\begin{align*}
\left(m(-1)^2-2(m-1)(-1)-m-1\right)\left(m2^2-2(m-1)2-m-1\right)&\lt0\\\
(2m-3)(-m+3) & \lt 0 \\\
-2m^2+9m-9 & \lt 0 \\\
 m \lt \frac{3}{2} \quad \vee \quad m \gt 3
\end{align*}
$

The thing is that this answer is **wrong** since the correct one is $m \lt \frac{3}{2} \quad \wedge \quad m \neq 0 \quad \vee \quad m \gt 3$. How do I get to know and not only verify that $m \neq 0$ what did I do wrong?

Using the theorems in the scenarios **I**.$ \quad x_1 \lt -1 \lt x_2 \lt 2$ and  **II**.$ \quad -1 \lt x_1 \lt 2 \lt x_2$, we have:

**I**.
$$x_1 \lt -1 \lt x_2 \lt 2
\implies \Bigl(af(-1) \lt 0\Bigr) \wedge  \Bigl(af(2) \gt 0\Bigr)  \wedge \Bigl(\Delta \gt 0 \Bigr)\wedge \Bigl( \frac{S}{2} \lt 2\Bigr).$$

**II**.
$$
-1 \lt x_1 \lt 2 \lt x_2 \implies
\Bigl( af(-1) \gt 0\Bigr)\wedge\Bigl( af(2) \lt 0\Bigr) \wedge \Bigl(\Delta \gt 0 \Bigr) \wedge\Bigl(\frac{S}{2} \gt -1 \Bigr)$$

So both **I** and **II** have the condition $\Delta \gt 0$ in common.
\begin{align*}
\Delta \gt 0 &\implies [-2(m-1)]^2-4m(-m-1) \gt 0\\\
&\implies 8m^2-4m+4 \gt 0 \\\
\end{align*}

The problem is that the $\Delta$ from the equation $8m^2-4m+4=0$ is negative. $\Delta = b^2-4ac = (-4)^2-4(8)(4) \lt 0 \implies \nexists m$ such that $8m^2-4m+4=0
\implies \nexists m$ such that $[-2(m-1)]^2-4m(-m-1) \gt 0$. So doesn't matter what the others conditions says in **I** (or in **II**), intersecting them all will give an empty set. And therefore **I** $\cup$ **II** will give $\emptyset$.

So I am doing it wrong both ways. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Your formatting really makes things hard to read and follow. You don't put arrows on both previous and next line, just on one of them. And don't use `.` for multiplication! It's too much like a decimal point. Either use `\times` or `\cdot` (the latter will produced a raised dot)

Comment: I am going to correct it now. Thanks. Right, I'll use \cdot or \times next time.

Comment: I would like someone to address the theorems solutions, please.

Comment: There are no "theorems solutions" here. There is your solution to the problem, and I *did* address it. I explained what your error was: it lies in assuming that because the discriminant of $\Delta$ is never zero, this means that $\Delta$ itself is never positive. That is not the case.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing that the reason for $m\neq 0$ is that if $m=0$, then your original equation,
$$mx^2-2(m-1)x - m - 1=0$$
becomes a **linear** equation, namely $2x - 1 = 0$. Presumably, they are asking that the equation actually have *two* roots, of which one and only one lies in the desired interval. While it is true that the equation $2x-1=0$ has one and only one solution between $-1$ and $2$ (namely, $x=\frac{1}{2}$), it has no solutions *outside* the interval, which is probably assumed in the statement.

Note that you did far too much work in the first method. From $(2m-3)(-m+3)\lt 0$, you are set: the two roots are $m=\frac{3}{2}$ and $m=3$; that means that $(2m-3)(m-3)$ takes negative values exactly between them; since you have this product times $-1$ (given the factor $(-m+3)$ instead of $(m-3)$), the negative values for $(2m-3)(-m+3) = -(2m-3)(m-3)$ occur exactly outside that interval: on $(-\infty,\frac{3}{2})$ and on $(3,\infty)$.

As for the second one, you are not thinking clearly. You want the discriminant positive, yes. The discriminant is $8m^2-4m+4$, yes. And the discriminant of *this* is negative, yes. And that means is that $8m^2-4m+4$ is *never zero*, yes. But you don't want it to be zero! You want it to be positive. You are looking for the values where it is zero so you can see where it may *change* from positive to negative. The fact that it is never zero tells you that it never **changes** from positive to negative or from negative to positive, so that means that is either always positive or always negative. Plugging in $m=0$ shows you that it is in fact *always positive*, so that the condition $\Delta \gt 0$ is *always* satsfied. It is the *exact opposite* of what you concluded: it's not that the condition is *never* satisfied, it is *always satisfied*, so you just need to check the other condition; $\Delta\gt 0$ will always hold.

Comment: @Arturo I see now why $m=0$ can't possible be a solution, since linear equations doesn't have roots at all. Yet thinking...

Comment: @Kaeser Linear equations do have roots.  Well, one root, anyway.  The linear equation $mx + b = 0$ has its root at $x = -\frac{b}{m}$.  I think Arturo was saying that the case when $m = 0$ violates the spirit of the problem, since the original question had to do with a quadratic equation and $m = 0$ makes the equation no longer quadratic.

Comment: Is it that $\Delta \gt 0$ is always satisfied because $8m^2-4m+4$ has its $a \gt 0$ and $\Delta  \lt 0$, such that all $m$'s make it positive?

Comment: @Alex: Oh I see what you meant. The question asks only for roots of the quadratic. Now I know linear equations have roots too. Thanks.

Comment: @Kaeser: When you have a quadratic with negative discriminant, it is either always positive or always negative; in particular, if when evaluated at $0$ it is positive, then it is always positive, and if when evaluated at $0$ it is negative, then it will always be negative. In this case, the quadratic $8m^2-4m+4$ has negative discriminant, and at $0$ the value is $4$, which is positive. Since it can never cross the $x$-axis (it is never equal to $0$, because its discriminant is negative), and it is positive in at least one place, it is **always** positive. So positive for all values of $m$.

Comment: @Kaeser: I'll add that you see some of the major disadvantages of your notation. You are using, in your next to last comment, $\Delta$ to mean **two different things**. The first time you use it, it refers to $8m^2-4m+4$; the second, it refers to $(-4)^2-4(4)(8)$. This is likely at least partly to blame for your confusion. You should **never** use the same symbol to mean two different things at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT** $\ $ The case $\rm\: m = 0\:$ should not be excluded since then $\rm\: f = 2\ x - 1\ $ which has only 1 root (between -1 and 2). If, alternatively, you require that there be another root outside the interval then you need to determine the case(s) where the prior argument breaks down due to the quadratic degenerating to a lower degree polynomial. Here that is precisely when the leading coefficient vanishes, i.e. $\rm\: m = 0\:$. So the argument really is no more difficult than the simple proof I gave in the original thread.

Comment: @Bill: It all depends on the exact phrasing. If they want one root in the interval, *and the other one* outside, then $m=0$ is excluded because it fails the second condition.

Comment: @Arturo: But, if that's what's desired, then it is obvious what to do in this degenerate case - as I remarked.

Comment: So $f(a)f(b) \lt 0$ is never fully sufficient to find out $m$? Does it means I need always plug $m=0$ additionally, and then, it will be enough? Thanks for the answers.

Comment: No: *my* point is that if you want the equation to have **TWO** roots (as opposed to just one) you need to make sure the equation remains a quadratic. In this case, the leading coefficient is $m$: if $m=0$, then the leading coefficient is $0$, and the equation is not a quadratic, but a linear equation. It's not that $0$ is magical in some way, it's that this is what makes the leading coefficient vanish **in this case.**

Comment: @Bill: Yes, I agree; I'm just guessing why they are excluding $m=0$. We are not seeing the original wording of the problem, just the report of what the answer "is supposed to be", and the report of what the problem "is". Of course it's easy to see what to do in the degenerate case; this has never stopped people who write precalculus drill from doing otherwise.

Comment: @Kaeser: If a proof depends on a polynomial having degree 2 then you need to handle any lower degree (degenerate) cases separately.

Comment: I am thinking here. Don't know what to comment. I will keep thinking.